# Finding λ in an exponential distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

When $ λ $ is given with a given probablity of $X$, it's a simple program, where for example I can do

```
f[x_] := 7*Exp[-7 x]
Probability[x > 2, x ≈ ExponentialDistribution[7]] // N
```

but what if $X$ is exponentially distributed random variable with some parameter $ λ $. 
How would you find possible values of $ λ $, if you are only given the probability with its range of $X$ and its probability of getting these ranges  $(eg: Pr(0.2≤X≤1.7) = 0.14 )$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `λ` instead of 7 in your [`Probability`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Probability) expression, and solve:

```
Solve[
    Probability[.2 ≤ x ≤ 1.7, Distributed[x, ExponentialDistribution[λ]]] == .14,
    λ,
    Reals
]
```

> Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.
>
> {{λ -> 0.102807}, {λ -> 9.83056}}

Comment: NSolve works best